# How is floating point overflow handled in iostreams

Tags: c++, g++, iostream

I have some very simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stringstream is("1.0 2.0 1e-500 1e500 12.0");
  double d = {17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0};

  for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    if (is >> d[i])
    {
      cout<<"Conversion succeeded"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"Conversion failed"<<endl;
      is.clear();
    }
  }
  for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) cout<<d[i]<<endl;
}
```

When I compile this code with g++ 4.1.2 and run it on Redhat 5.10 (same compiler), I get the output:

```
Conversion succeeded
Conversion succeeded
Conversion failed
Conversion failed
Conversion succeeded
1
2
0
17
17
12
```

When I execute the same binary on Redhat Linux 6.5 (compiler 4.4.7), I get

```
Conversion succeeded
Conversion succeeded
Conversion succeeded
Conversion failed
Conversion succeeded
1
2
0
1.79769e+308
12
```

What is the expected behavior?  Underflow is succeeeding on 4.4.7 but failing on 4.1.2.  Overflow fails (but still changes the value) on 4.4.7 and fails without changing anything on 4.1.2.

Is the behavior undefined or simply incorrect on one or the other?

Comment: Good question. `>>` is indirectly (via `num_get`) defined in terms of the rules of `strtold`, and for the latter, it is explicitly unspecified whether underflow is treated as an error condition. However, underflow is *not* treated as one of the error conditions for `num_get`. I'm not sure what whether that means it's unspecified, or well-defined as returning 0 successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to C++11 22.4.2.1.2, the conversion should fail for overflow, but not underflow. In the case of overflow, it should still give a value of the largest representable value as well as setting `failbit`.

So your more recent compiler has the correct modern behaviour.

However, both of your ancient compilers predate C++11 by many years. In earlier standards, the conversion was specified to give an error if `scanf` would; and not to give a value in case of error. Turning to the C standard, `scanf` defers to `strtod`, which in turn specifies an error on overflow; but whether there's an error on underflow is implementation-defined.

So your older compiler is consistent with historical behaviour.